# Array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15"
is the error message I get when running my code, I assume it is trying to use a number which is larger than the array or something along those lines; heres my code:

```
public class TileGrid {

public Tile[][] map;

public TileGrid(){
    map = new Tile[20][15];
    for(int i=0; i<map.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<map[i].length; j++){
            map[i][j]=new Tile(i*64, j*64, 64, 64, TileType.grass);
        }
    }
}
public void Draw(){
    for(int i=0; i<map.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; i<map[i].length;j++){
            Tile t = map[i][j];
            DrawQuadTex(t.getTexture(), t.getX(), t.getY(), t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());

        }
    }
}
```

My code is in multiple classes, which I will paste as well if needed

Comment: In `Draw`: `int j=0; i<map[i]` here: `i <` should be `j < `!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is broken. You incorrectly have `i < map[i].length`, the `i` here should be a `j`!

```
for(int i=0; i<map.length;i++){
    for(int j=0; j < map[i].length; j++){
```

Comment: thanks so much, I was blind after doing it for so long

Comment: Np! If this has solved the problem for you, please mark this answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `i<map[i]` with `j<map[i]` like this:

```
  for(int j=0; j<map[i].length;j++){
```

Not:

```
  for(int j=0; i<map[i].length;j++){
```

You used the wrong index.